# How to send data from the view to the controller cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a search function in my controller, and I would like to send 2 variables from the view to the controller so it can process it.., an `$id` and a `$value` . This is because I am using a drop down to allow to select the search type, and an input to search for.. What is the best way to do this:?

crontroller

```
function search($id, $value) {
  switch($id)
  {
    case '0':
      // todo
    break;

    case '1':
      // todo
    break;

    case '2':
      // todo
    break;

    case '3':
      // todo
    break;

    default:
      $this->set('dishes', $this->Dish->find('all')); 
    break;
  }
  $this->layout = 'main_layout';
}
```

Comment: You need to do an ajax request, potentially to a different action in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

in your view you can use get method to send the form data. and in your controller's action you can access the passed arguments with $this->params['url'];

in your view

```
   $this->Form->create('Model', array('type' => 'get', 'action' => 'search'));
   $this->Form->input('select_tfield_id', array('type' => 'select'));
   $this->Form->input('value'));
   $this->Form->end('submit');
```

In your controller

```
   function search() {
       $url = $this->params['url'];
       $id = $url['select_tfield_id'];
       $value = $url['value'];
   }
```